# Cannot assign values to typed array buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, variable-assignment, typed-arrays

How come the value is not getting assigned as expected? No errors are thrown.

```
fs = require('fs');
var path="data.dat";
var f = fs.createReadStream(path,{highWaterMark:1024*1024*128})
var stat = fs.statSync(path);
var stream = fs.createReadStream(path,{start:0,end:stat.size-1});
var dat = new Float64Array(stat.size);
var idx = 0;
stream.on('data',(chunk)=>{
    var temp = new Float64Array((new Uint8Array(chunk)).buffer);
    for(var i = 0; i< temp.length;++i){
        dat[idx++]=temp[i];
        console.log(temp[i]); //this will log the expected values
        console.log(dat[idx]); //this will log a bunch of 0
    }

});
stream.on('end',function(){
    //do_stuff(dat);
});
```

Comment: To print the *dat* value you should use *idx* and not increment it again.

Comment: Oops, that was a copy and paste mistake (corrected now). It still doesn't work though. The entire array is a bunch of 0.

Comment: You have increased idx twice.. to make code simpler to follow just remove the inline ++, and just do another line idx++ at then end of block.  Also looking at the code you have not taken into account any Float64 length.

Comment: Sorry my bad, if you use an index in array and you increment it, you point the next value, that here doesn't exists. You should use *idx-1* to get the index you used, because the increment works after the variable id used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urrgg... I feel stupid for asking. The answer is console.log(dat[idx-1]);

Comment: Right :) but don't feel stupid, most of the issues are like this.

Comment: I also made the mistake of trying to access the variable outside of the .on('end' which made it seem like I just had a bunch of 0s